# esp8266- how to use GPIO0 as an input?

Tags: arduino-uno

First, my setup:
I have an Arduino Uno with an Adafruit Audio Shield.  I have a Wemos D1 Mini controlling the project.

I need for the D1 to know when a file is playing.

I have a GPIO pin on the Uno programmed to be high when a file is playing.  Low otherwise.  I have two GPIO pins on the Wemos that are unused, D3 and D4 (GPIO0 and GPIO2).  (I use a divider circuit of a 10K over a 20K resistor to bring the 5V from the Uno down to 3v3 for the Wemos). D4 is already a problem because it has to be high to boot and the GPIO from the Uno is normally low. D3 (GPIO0) has to be high to boot and has an internal pullup.

Here's my problem.  How do I turn off the pullup on GPIO0? Even when the Uno GPIO is low (0V), the GPIO0 measures 2.4V, which my sketch sees as a logical 1.

Any tips would be appreciated.  (I thought of reversing the polarity on the Uno so that low=true, but even when the Uno is driving the pin low, the Wemos GPIO0 pin is still at 2.4V, so low-true logic won't work either.).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the voltage divider and never set the Uno pin HIGH.

Pull io 0 of esp8266 LOW with pinMode of the Uno pin.

```
pinMode(TO_ESP_IO0, OUTPUT); // sets the pin LOW

pinMode(TO_ESP_IO0, INPUT); // let it to the io0 pull-up resistor
```